# Alert is not blocked by sync calls before that

Tags: javascript

I created this sample web page to create a delay by running the same blocking call multiple times. The issue here is, It's taking some time javascript to count to 50,000 (around 4 seconds) at least it looks like so in the javascript console but the alert call is running before chrome finish counting to 50,000. Why is that?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
<body>
    <script>

        for(let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            console.log("Loaded")
        }

        alert("loaded")

        console.log('WEB PAGE: Hello World')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it is just a display issue. The displaying of the console could be async.

Comment: Everything is working expected !! Can you provide `snippet` stating your question ? Use `<>` when you edit your question and add an example

Comment: If i simply try the above `JS code` in chrome console. My alert is popping after couple of seconds and difference between console log and alert is in fraction of second. So it's valid

Comment: I'm not able to replicate it, I tried it on Firefox though. The console logs 50000 times and only then does the alert box pop up.

Comment: it looks like you are simulating page load.  If your intent is to alert once the entire page has loaded, you can just make use of a the [window.onLoad()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event handler.

Comment: @theapologist open a new tab. open the console in that. open the page after that. It's immediately sowing the alert. But not after page reloads though. It's so weird.
https://imgur.com/ZwUkJhp

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong what your seeing is the delay the browser creates.

Drop the logging in the for loop and use it just to loop that many times will make everything faster.

Note: your not really not describing the point. If the point is to wait for 50,000 what does that mean? is it seconds or less? Is this just a test for some slow api call? Or simply to write out 1-50,000? if you could explain more the answer may be much easier to provide.

see my comment for this add:

```
var count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
        count++;
    }
console.log(count);
```

Comment: `Nothing is wrong what your seeing is the delay the browser creates`
to do what?
If I drop the log how do I know if it's actually looped it 50000 times?
Within brackets, I have mentioned it's around 4 seconds

Comment: its the delay between the browser logging your .log and the display of it. if you want to test it loops that many times try my new change to my answer (cant add here)

Answer (score 1):

console.log will queue the data and write it when the process ends, it doesn't write strings synchronously and because you queued a lot of data, the browser finished counting and showed the alert before the console data was shown.